How to run a Camel-K integration based on Camel 3.22.2
I need to use a component that is present in Camel 3 but not yet in version 4.
Via JBang I am able to drive the library version by getting it to run correctly:
camel run --camel-version=3.22.2 testLegacyComp.xml
However trying the following command I cannot create the relative integration:
./kamel run testLegacyComp.xml -dev --logs -t camel.runtime-version=2.16.0 -V
PS:
is it correct to indicate version 2.16.0 considering this output?
kubectl get CamelCatalogs
NAME RUNTIME PROVIDER RUNTIME VERSION CAMEL VERSION PHASE
camel-catalog-1.17.1 quarkus 1.17.1 3.20.1 Ready
camel-catalog-2.16.0 quarkus 2.16.0 3.20.1 Ready
camel-catalog-3.2.0 quarkus 3.2.0 4.0.0 Ready
camel-catalog-3.8.1 quarkus 3.8.1 4.4.1 Ready

I'm looking for the correct approach/command to run a flow based on Camel 3.x on an updated Camel-K

I think this question was solved in the official Camel K chatroom topic.
The syntax is correct. -dev parameter was wrong, and should be --dev.
